# Check if clickhouse is healthy docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, clickhouse

I need to wait for Clickhouse to start before I can start my backend server, however the healthcheck does not work.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  server:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      clickhouse:
        condition: service_healthy

  clickhouse:
    image: yandex/clickhouse-server
    ports:
      - '8123:8123'
      - '9000:9000'
      - '9009:9009'
    healthcheck:
      test: ['CMD', 'curl', '-f', 'http://localhost:8123']
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 5
```

However when I run `docker-compose up --build`, then you can see the Clickhouse server starting, everything is fine, however the healthcheck never passes. The command exits preemptively with the error: `container for service "Clickhouse" is unhealthy`. However, if, during this time, I go run the command `curl -f http://localhost:8123` on my own computer (outside of the docker container) then it returns `Ok.`

So is there a way to wait for Clickhouse to be healthy before starting another service?

Comment: are you sure curl present inside container?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this way:

```yaml
    ..
    healthcheck:
      test: wget --no-verbose --tries=1 --spider http://localhost:8123/?query=SELECT%201 || exit 1
    ..
```

or

```yaml
    ..
    healthcheck:
      test: wget --no-verbose --tries=1 --spider http://localhost:8123/ping || exit 1
    ..
```